# How to close application choice popup in Chrome?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-application, chrome

Is there is any option to close application choice pop up in Chrome, which occurs after clicking any call number button in mobile emulation?

[image]

Comment: What about clicking cancel ?

Comment: I mean automatically, using any Selenium actions, or Chrome built-in options. This popup is not alert, so Selenium's `driver.switch_to_alert()` doesn't work here.

Comment: I understand it is not an alert.  That is why I suggest clicking cancel on whatever part of the DOM it occupies.

Comment: It seems like Chrome only popup, not an web app part, so it doesn't occur in DOM. It also block any touch interactions with web site while popup is shown.

Comment: have you tried using `driver.switch_to_alert().accept` or `driver.switch_to_alert().dismiss` ?

Comment: @ornichola what is the test? do you need to check if the pop up appears and then close it or you just need to suppress the popup?

Comment: @NarendraR, this is not web page alert

Comment: @AlexeyR. my goal is to continue interaction with web page, but tests cannot do it untill this Chrome pop up is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an alert. It looks like browser notification.

Try this [Browser level notification](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-handle-browser-level-notification-using-selenium-webdriver-maske)